# How do I make the urls display in full in a powershell console?

Tags: powershell, sharepoint

When I am running

```
$s = Get-SPSite <my_site>
$s.AllWebs
```

I am unable to see long urls. After some length , the ulrs end with a few dots. How do I make the urls display in full in a powershell console ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$s = Get-SPSite <my_site>
$s.AllWebs | Format-Table -Autosize
```